# Grammar usage of causative verb

Tags: causatives, causative-get

Can we say "Why don't you get him to come here?"?

"Get" means to  convince someone.

So does the sentence express what I want to say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Why don't you get him to come here?

The idiom is: to get someone to do something.

Meaning: convince or persuade a person to do something.

Use of get like this is very useful in everyday English.